# How to use jquery to get the dynamic ID through a dynamic class name?

Tags: jquery

**jquery**

```
$("#add-to-basket").click(function() {
var frm = $( "#addtocart input" ).attr("id").hasClass( "selected" )
var frmarr = jQuery.makeArray( frm );
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});

});
```

the above syntax of $( "#addtocart input" ).attr("id").hasClass( "selected" ) is not correct, and I am not able to find the correct syntax or logic to correct it. I want to get all the ids of elements that has class == "selected" store them in an array and the send to php to be process trough ajax

## addtocart  is a form

inside the form I  have dynamic

**HTML**

```
while (fetch the rows from db)
 <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $OPlayer1num ; ?>" id="<?php echo $OPid.$seperator.$OPlayer2ID ;?>" class="css-IMGcheckbox" onClick="selectImg(this.id)" />  in a while loop inside the form
}
```

Comment: Even if your `$( "#addtocart input" ).attr("id").hasClass( "selected" )` is correct then it's going to return you `boolean` value!

Comment: is 'selected' really a class or are you refering to selected attribute ?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak is correct. The `hasClass()` method checks if any of the selected elements have a specified class name.

If ANY of the selected elements has the specified class name, this method will return "true". [Details](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_hasclass.asp)

Comment: Kindly refer to this link [Jquery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find out how jquery select the elements.

Comment: Any chance we can see you HTML?? The final generated HTML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do like this:

```
var frmarr  = new Array();

$("input.selected" ).each(function(){


console.log($(this).attr("id"));

fromarr.push($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Djhg/)